# Show $p'(x) + kp(x)$ has a zero between consecutive roots of the polynomial $p$

Tags: real-analysis

For any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and any polynomial $p(x)$, show that
$$p'(x) + kp(x)$$
has a zero between consecutive roots of $p$.

I have tried writing $p(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$, but this does not give a simple form.

I have tried applying the mean value theorem, but this just gives an $x_0$ with $p'(x_0) = 0$, and then $kp(x_0) \neq 0$, which is not what we want.

I have tried considering $x^k p(x)$, but this gives $x^{k-1}(p'(x) x + kp(x))$, which is not quite what we want. Similarly, I have tried using the quotient rule, to no avail.

I have tried the intermediate value theorem, but this only works when $p'(a)$ and $p'(b)$ have the opposite signs, where $a, b$ are consecutive zeroes.

Running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(e^{kx}p(x))'=e^{kx}(p'(x)+kp(x))$.

Comment: Brilliant! So simple...

Comment: It seems like the assumptions that $p$ is a polynomial, and that the roots are consecutive are unnecessary.

Comment: You are right in your suspicion:)